# File counter adds 2 instead of 1

Tags: php, counter, fread, fwrite

I made a simple counter, but it increments by 2 instead of 1.

```
    $handle = fopen('progress.txt', 'r');
    $pro = fgets($handle);
    print $pro; // incremented by 2, WTF?
    fclose($handle);

    $handle = fopen('progress.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($handle, $pro);
    fclose($handle);
```

Everytime I read the file it has been incremented by 2, instead of 1.

Comment: Where do you increment `$pro`?

Comment: The problem is not with the code you're showing - which doesn't even show where the counter is incremented.

Comment: Sorry, the original code increments after print $pro;

Comment: mod_rewrite is used on the site eh? :)

Comment: I've tried ++$pro, $pro++, $pro = $pro + 1, (string) $pro + 1, and numerous more, at different positions. When I print the value it shows a correct increment of 1.

Comment: Something to note : since there's a chance that multiple users will have concurrent access to the counter you should lock the file exclusively (using flock) before updating the counter, and release it after you have written the new value.

Comment: They wont. It is used for internal use to keep track of an updating process for a large XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here is the answer, based on the comment:

Be careful with front controller based on the mod_rewrite, as it act as a 404 error handler. And your browser tries to fetch favicon.ico with each request... ;)

By the way, I really love other answers. The real SO way.

Comment: It was actually because it was fetching a CSS file, which accessed the same script, therefore running the code twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $handle = fopen('progress.txt', 'r');
 $pro = fgets($handle);
 print $pro; // incremented by 2, WTF?
 $pro++;
 fclose($handle);

 $handle = fopen('progress.txt', 'w');
 fwrite($handle, $pro);
 fclose($handle);
```

That seems to work for me

Comment: My only guess could be something like Col. Shrapnel mentioned, where perhaps the page is actually being accessed twice for some reason like the site using mod-rewrite.

Comment: That's it! The script was indeed run twice because of this.

Thank you Col. Shrapnel and kilrizzy.